# Validate that an integer is not too big for database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an integer field in Mysql

```
t.integer  "client_number"
```

In my Rails model I have

```
validates_numericality_of :client_number
```

This works fine if a non number value is entered in the client_number field.

However if the user enters a number that is too big to be stored in an integer database field then it passes validation and I get a

```
Mysql2::Error Out of range value for column 'client_number'
```

I want to be able to capture the error from within the validator to prevent the database exception.

Is there any way of doing this generically across my application rather than laboriously doing something like the following on all integer fields:

```
validates_numericality_of :client_number, :only_integer=> true , :less_than_or_equal_to => 2147483647 , :greater_than => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: define a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) and then use it on whatever fields you like throughout your app.